# MVC Core 2.1: Multiple custom attributes of the same type found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a model written up. I went to scaffold the controller and received the following error:

Multiple custom attributes of the same type found.

I looked at my model a dozen times and I am not seeing duplicate attributes on any of the properties. I am not sure what is going on here.

```
using Supplies.Web.Resources;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Supplies.Web.Models
{
    public class Inventory
    {
        public Inventory()
        {
            this.IsActive = true;
        }

        [Column(TypeName = "int")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(AutoGenerateField = false, AutoGenerateFilter = false, Description = "Is active.", Name = "IsActive", Prompt = "IsActive", ResourceType = typeof(PropNames), ShortName = "Is Active")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = null, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SysMsg))]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(250)")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(AutoGenerateField = false, AutoGenerateFilter = false, Description = "Item description.", Name = "ItemDescription", Prompt = "ItemDescription", ResourceType = typeof(PropNames), ShortName = "Item Description")]
        [MaxLength(250)]
        [MinLength(10)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = null, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SysMsg))]
        [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = null, ErrorMessageResourceName = "LengthBetween", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SysMsg), MinimumLength = 10)]
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(AutoGenerateField = false, AutoGenerateFilter = false, Description = "MFG.", Name = "MFG", Prompt = "MFG", ResourceType = typeof(PropNames), ShortName = "MFG")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [MinLength(2)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = null, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SysMsg))]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = null, ErrorMessageResourceName = "LengthBetween", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SysMsg), MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string MFG { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "int")]
        [Display(AutoGenerateField = false, AutoGenerateFilter = false, Description = "Reorder level.", Name = "ReorderLevel", Prompt = "ReorderLevel", ResourceType = typeof(PropNames), ShortName = "Reorder Level")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = null, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SysMsg))]
        public int ReorderLevel { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "int")]
        [Display(AutoGenerateField = false, AutoGenerateFilter = false, Description = "Reorder quantity.", Name = "ReorderQuantity", Prompt = "ReorderQuantity", ResourceType = typeof(PropNames), ShortName = "Reorder Quantity")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = null, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SysMsg))]
        public int ReorderQuantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was searching around and found something that might be useful and now it works.

You cannot seem to use [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)] and [EmailAddress] together.

Similarly, the same  goes for [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)] and [Phone]

You could do this in EF6, but seems Core doesn't like it? This is so strange.

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar(128)")]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Display(AutoGenerateField = false, AutoGenerateFilter = false, Description = "Email address.", Name = "EmailAddress", Prompt = "EmailAddress", ResourceType = typeof(PropNames), ShortName = "Email Address")]
//[EmailAddress]
[MaxLength(128)]
[MinLength(6)]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = null, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SysMsg))]
[StringLength(128, ErrorMessage = null, ErrorMessageResourceName = "LengthBetween", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SysMsg), MinimumLength = 6)]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Comment: [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)] and [EmailAddress] was for me the reason